# Instantiating Objects with data from DB changes values

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I am working on a location based game that displays the location of each player on a map.

So every client uploads lat, lon and his playername to a MySQL DB.
after retrieving the query and splitting the values into an array the markers for each player get loaded successfully on their correct position, but their player names switch to the next marker.

```
public  void CreatePlayerAvatars()
{
    GameObject[] allObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PlayerMarker");
    foreach(GameObject obj in allObjects) {
        Destroy(obj);
    }
    float worldScale = FindObjectOfType<AbstractMap>().WorldRelativeScale;
    Vector2d mapCenter = FindObjectOfType<AbstractMap>().CenterMercator;
    if (PlayerGeoLocation != null && PlayerGeoLocation.text.Length > 0 )
    {
    // data from db
        string data = playerDataString.Replace(",",".");

        string[] datasets = data.Split('¡');

         try
            {          
                foreach(string item in datasets)
                    {

                        string[] Itemdata = item.Split('œ');

                        string id = Itemdata[0];
                        print(id);
                        string name = Itemdata[1];
                        print("name "+name);
                        string Lat = Itemdata[2];
                        print("lat: "+Lat);
                        string Lon = Itemdata[3];
                        print("Lon: " + Lon);

                        PlayerLat = Convert.ToDouble(Lat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        PlayerLon = Convert.ToDouble(Lon, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


                        Vector3 InstancePosition = Conversions.GeoToWorldPosition(PlayerLat, PlayerLon, mapCenter, worldScale).ToVector3xz(); // This needs a reference point!

                        Instantiate(PlayerMarker, InstancePosition, Quaternion.identity );

                        PlayerLable = PlayerMarkerCanvas.GetComponent<Text>();
                        PlayerLable.text = name;}} catch()}}
```

no error messages just the switcheroo..

If anyone has a hint it would be much appreciated. 
thanks for the time

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I added the Label text after instantiating.